# What can cause python to hang on exception?

Tags: python, python-2.7, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 machine running python 2.7.5. The server ran out of disk space and memory, and I had to restart it, and now python hangs if it hits an uncaught exception.

Example:

```
echo "raise Exception()" > /tmp/test.py
python /tmp/test.py
# (hangs until killed with kill -9)
```

I don't have a problem if the exception is inside a try..except clause. I also don't have a problem in the interactive shell.

Strangely, I don't even see the problem if I run python -c, example:

```
# python -c "raise Exception()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Exception
```

I thought the problem had something to do with creating the traceback, but this program works fine:

```
import traceback
traceback.print_stack()
```

I also have python 3.6 installed, and that works fine, but doesn't help my situation. I'm having problems with yum, probably because of the python problems.

Any ideas or debugging directions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `strace python test.py` to see where it gets stuck. `strace` might have to be installed first.

Answer (score 0):

After using strace it became obvious that my problem was a corrupt rpm DB, as it got stuck shortly after this line:

```
open("/var/lib/rpm/__db.003", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644) = 6
```

I was able to rebuild my DB with these commands:

```
rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db*        
/usr/lib/rpm/rpmdb_verify /var/lib/rpm/Packages
```

Everything works fine now. Thanks @klaus-d!